# coding data for neural net

Tags: r, neural-network

I have got troubles with processing data to use it in neural net, my table looks like this one:

```
drug.name    molecular.target         molecular.weight

drug1        target1                  225
drug2        target2,target3          210
drug3        target4,target1          120
drug4        target1,target2,target3  110
                     (...)
```

As I found before I will be able to use the data in  it should be trensformed to dummy variables. I have no idea how to deal with multiple values in column with targets to have matrix like this one:

```
drug.name molecular.weight  target1  target2 target3(...)

drug1     225               1        0       0
drug2     225               0        1       1 
                          (...)
```

the data set is quiet big so i am not able to create and fill new columns manually.

I hope you understand me ;) 
Sebastian

Comment: I don't have a solution at this point but I can point you at some packages that would likely help: the combination of `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `stringr`.  Also, `data.table` could help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "hacky" solution but it seems to work for the small set I tested on.  There are a number of warnings but I am not sure how to make them to away.  If someone can suggests simplifications, I will update the answer.

NOTE: See solution in **EDIT** below, that addresses the change in the original question.  The initial solution immediately below addresses the original question asked.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

### Using this input data set
drug_df <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = '
drug.name    molecular.target         molecular.weight
drug1        target1                  225
drug2        target2,target3          210
drug3        target4,target1          120
drug4        target1,target2,target3  110')
drug_df

##  drug.name        molecular.target molecular.weight
##1     drug1                 target1              225
##2     drug2         target2,target3              210
##3     drug3         target4,target1              120
##4     drug4 target1,target2,target3              110

### Process the input data frame
targetset <- sort(unique(unlist(sapply(drug_df$molecular.target, function(x) str_split(x, ',')))))

drug_df_new <-
    drug_df %>%
    separate(molecular.target, targetset, ',')      %>% # Create new target columns
    gather(key, val, -drug.name, -molecular.weight) %>% # Put in deep format for further manipulation
    select(-key)                                    %>% # Remove key column, it isn't needed.
    filter(!is.na(val))                             %>% # Only want drug targets, not empty targets
    rename(key = val)                               %>% # "val" will be used as new "key"
    group_by(drug.name)                             %>% # Group to get target count
    mutate(val = n())                               %>% # set val to target count
    spread(key, val, fill = 0)                          # Put in final format

drug_df_new
##  drug.name molecular.weight target1 target2 target3 target4
##      (chr)            (int)   (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)
##1     drug1              225       1       0       0       0
##2     drug2              210       0       2       2       0
##3     drug3              120       2       0       0       2
##4     drug4              110       3       3       3       0
```

**EDIT**

The alternative solution below addresses the changes in the original post.  This obtains the result specified in the edited version of the post.  The above solution will be removed when the solution below is confirmed to work on the larger data set.

```
drug_df_new <-
     drug_df %>%
     separate(molecular.target, targetset, ',')      %>% # Create new target columns
     gather(key, val, -drug.name, -molecular.weight) %>% # Put in deep format for further manipulation
     mutate(new_val = ifelse(!is.na(val), 1, 0))     %>% # Create the new value 0 or 1
     select(-key)                                    %>% # Remove key column, it isn't needed.
     filter(!is.na(val))                             %>% # Remove lines where no target exists
     spread(val, new_val, fill = 0)                      # Put in longer format.

##  drug.name molecular.weight target1 target2 target3 target4
##1     drug1              225       1       0       0       0
##2     drug2              210       0       1       1       0
##3     drug3              120       1       0       0       1
##4     drug4              110       1       1       1       0
```

Comment: So i checked again values when i woke up, and your code is not working on my bigger data set, And i need convince my self that i made a mistake in question i need to have "binary event matrix" with only zeros and ones. I checked your code and it seems that after using separate() it makes a data frame with splited target column into multiple columns with names of targets but they are not assigned to right one, they are placed in order in which they are in the original column.

Comment: If it isn't working, can you provide a reproducible data sample where this breaks?  That would help troubleshoot.  If you do and I can't get the code working in the answer, I will remove it.

Comment: I found the solution, problem was caused by * in some of targets (target*) i solved it by adding glob2rx('target*') and it started to work thanks again for help